# Java remove all Exclamation point

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

i've a simple question, i need to remove all exclamation point from an HTML string in Java.
i've tried with

```
testo = testo.replaceAll("\\\\!", "! <br>");
```

and

```
regex = "\\s*\\b!\\b\\s*";
        testo = testo.replaceFirst(regex, "<br>");
```

and

```
 testo = testo.replaceAll("\\\\!", "! <br>");
```

But doesn't work. Can someone help me?
another little question, i need to replace 1, 2 or 3 exclamation point with a single breakline
thank's to all!

Comment: What are you escaping `!` for? :> Anyway, consider `replaceAll("!+", "! <br>")`

Comment: thank's! it work!  don't know this escape

Comment: `!` isn't special (by itself) in a regular expression syntax. `+` means "match one or more times". See Jerry's answer if you only want to match *up to* 3 times (my previous comment will match as many "!" in a row as there are: e.g. 1, 4 .. or 5000 times).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need regex for this? You can simply do `String#replace`

```
testo = testo.replace("!", "! <br>");
```

However to remove multiple exclamation marks use:

```
testo = testo.replaceAll("!+", "! <br>");
```

Comment: "i need to replace 1, 2 or 3 exclamation point with a single breakline"

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to escape the exclamation mark:

```
testo = testo.replaceAll("!{1,3}", "! <br>");
```

Should do.

`{1,3}` means 1 to 3 consecutive occurrences.